# Какие есть лицензии на продукты интеллектуального труда? Как посоветуете защитить и в каком виде?

Tags: лицензирование

У меня есть учебный материал. Есть сайт с ним (отформатированный текст и виз. оформление). Могу сделать PS/dvi/pdf файл через TEX. Могу что-то с текстбоксами на C/GTK слепить. Как лучше и с какими лицензиями: программными или какой-нибудь CreativeLicense (вообще не в курсах)?

Comment: Лучше придерживаться позиции -- информация должна быть свободной.

Comment: Спасибо avp и Vlad.

Comment: @deja0x10, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Для начала: мы не юристы, поэтому всё, что мы говорим, воспринимайте по принципу «доверяй, но проверяй».

В любом случае, если вы публикуете софт, хорошей идеей является указать лицензию. Если хотите следовать принципам свободы информации — выберите одну из свободных лицензий (см. ниже списки). Если нет, вам придётся подумать, чем вы собираетесь ограничить пользователя, и либо попросить юриста составить лицензию для вас, либо подобрать самому подходящую (смотрите, чтобы у вас было право её использовать!).

Вот вроде бы [хороший обзор на русском](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ru.html), охватывает как свободные, так и некоторые коммерческие лицензии. Вот ещё информация о свободных лицензиях: [[1]](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical), [[2]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: @Kromster: Спасибо! Не смог вспомнить, что была за ссылка тогда, добавил новые ссылки.